# How to click on a non clickable element?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, automation, appium

I am trying to automate a **android** app but, the element that I need to click on has a non clickable attribute in the node detail.

I wrote this line of code in hopes of success but, my attempt hasn't worked.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).click();
```

[image]

Can anyone steer me in the right direction? I'm lost. Thank you in advance.

Comment: does that frame contains two elements(parent frame)?

Comment: you can wait for sometimes until the elements appear using **ExplicitWait**  or Thread.sleep(). Thread.sleep is not the recommended way. Also you can check if you are able to tap on element using appium desktop inspector.

Comment: @suban the element is not clickable how did he suppose to click , he can wait but no use

Comment: Even if it is shown the element is not clickable in the uiautomatorviewer or appium inspector, you will be able to click the element if the element have the onClick event

Comment: I've tried using the Thread.sleep() approach but, my appium logs give me a nosuchelement exception, sometimes it doesn't give me an error at all, it just stops at that point. It's weird because the code I posted above works when used on an emulator but, if I try to run the same code on my phone, it fails at that point.

Comment: Try moving up the tree (parent containers) until you find one that's clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get a [position of that element](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/rect/), then you can just tap by coordinates.

Comment: Rectangle rect = driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).getRect() and then https://discuss.appium.io/t/tapping-on-the-screen-by-using-coordinates/5529

Answer (score 0):

**@Damone Williams**,  I have a kind of feeling that You're using incorrect element locator (attribute ID).

Could You please connect device and try out Chrome/Safari Remote debugger. 
I'd recommend to switch to Web Element inspector  and ensure element You're attempting to click on -  can be found in Element inspector.

Here is [step-by-step manual](https://experitest.com/mobile-testing/app-dev-debug-anywhere/)  how to establish Chrome/Safari Remote debugger.
Later on  (in ~2hours) from now I will share explanatory video-snap with instructions.

Hope this helps for You.
Best regards,
Eugene